# Using MultiField annotation in an entity class for use with elastic search

Tags: java, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am currently using Spring boot 2.7.0 and spring data elastic search 4.4.0 with ELK 7.17.4. Having an issue in using MultiField annotation.
Getting a MappingException, but the annotation has been used correctly.
Both the Annotation definition and Validation code are part of Spring data elastic search 4.4.0, so at a conflict here. Please see below.

Have an entity class:

````
@MultiField(mainField = @Field(type = FieldType.Text, fielddata = true, analyzer = LOWER_KEYWORD_ANALYZER, searchAnalyzer = LOWER_KEYWORD_ANALYZER),
            otherFields = {
                    @InnerField(suffix = "sort", type = FieldType.Keyword, index = false),
                    @InnerField(suffix = "raw", type = FieldType.Keyword, index = false)
            })
    private Set<String> myProp = new HashSet<>();
    ```
    
Getting an error:
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: @Field annotation must not be used on a @MultiField property

Error stack trace:
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: @Field annotation must not be used on a @MultiField property.
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.mapping.SimpleElasticsearchPersistentProperty.<init>(SimpleElasticsearchPersistentProperty.java:100) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.0.jar:4.4.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.mapping.SimpleElasticsearchMappingContext.createPersistentProperty(SimpleElasticsearchMappingContext.java:77) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.0.jar:4.4.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.mapping.SimpleElasticsearchMappingContext.createPersistentProperty(SimpleElasticsearchMappingContext.java:34) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.0.jar:4.4.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:603) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:581) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:714) ~[spring-core-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.doAddPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:449) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:406) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:291) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:209) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:92) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$6(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:325) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:183) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:325) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:69) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.0.jar:4.4.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
````

Answer (score 1):

This exception is thrown when you have a `@MultiField` **and** a `@Field` annotation on the same property. Alas you do not show the full entity class.

Comment: The MultiField annotation definition includes Field annotation as a required member:
```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Documented
public @interface MultiField {
    Field mainField();

    InnerField[] otherFields() default {};
}```

Comment: The entity class had one member that was incorrectly defined with both Field and MultiField annotation. After removing the Field annotation, it is now working fine. Thank you.